# CakePHP 3 - using OR in Conditions?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How do i use an "OR" condition in CakePHP? So far, this is what i got:

```
$sales_transactions = $transactionsTable->find('all', [
        'conditions' => [
            'or' => [
                'transaction_date LIKE' => '2019-01-%',
                'transaction_date LIKE' => '2020-01-%'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

However, that is simply an array with a duplicate key so it only uses the last part (the 2020 date) - i wanna get all transactions out that has a year of EITHER 2019 or 2020 (so something like SELECT *** WHERE transaction_date LIKE '2020-01-%' OR transaction_date LIKE '2019-01-%'.

But no matter what i try, i only get 1 year and it uses AND - i can't get it to use OR as a condition.

Any help appriciated here, thanks all! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Oh right i just figured it out, you have to put the conditions in the OR array in their own arrays, like this:

```
$sales_transactions = $transactionsTable->find('all', [
        'conditions' => [
            'device_id IN' => $deviceIDSinDepartment,
            'customer_id' => 0,
            'or' => [
                ['transaction_date LIKE' => '' . $date->format('Y-m') . '-%'],
                ['transaction_date LIKE' => '' . $dateLastYear->format('Y-m') . '-%']
            ]
        ],
        'contain' => [
            'products'
        ],
        'group' => [
            'DATE(transaction_date)',
            'is_leftover'
        ]
    ]);
```